# Is icloud drive on desktop storing file on my locally or on the cloud?

Tags: icloud

Question is simple, i subscribe to a 200GB icloud drive.
My desktop has 60GB available for storage (on SSD)

Will i be able to fill my icloud drive with data from my dying USB external drive, and can you explain me how to do that ? (i just put 20GB from my external drive to C:\mysuser\icloudrive\stuffs\ and now i only have 40GB available on my windows 7 C:\ ), 180Go remain to be transfert, how can i do that ?